# Parser Error: unexpected character at line 3 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller

I have a project and I host it into my local server.
`path:C:\inetpub\wwwroot`
and my project worked as expected, but when I create a directory inside `C:\inetpub\wwwroot like`
`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Link1` ajax post method shows me-

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 3 column 1 of the JSON data

Am I missing something???
any kind of help would be appreciated.

code in js file:

```
var besiscid = $("#basictypeids").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
var list = {
            BASICTYPEID: besiscid
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Invoice/_GetInvoiceNumber",
            data: JSON.stringify(list),
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (objDAL) {
                alert(objDAL.DINVOICENO);  
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                alert(jqXHR);
                alert(textStatus);
                alert(error);
            }
        });
```

Comment: You should try to `console.log( list )`

Comment: It's not possible because i need the value which is come form objDAL.DINVOICENO, and i find it when my project live in wwwroot,but when i move my project into wwwroot/Link1 a subdirectory objDAL.DINVOICENO lost it's value